# Jquery post - Form submit cancelling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm having trouble with my small web-app. I want to disable that the form will submit.

At the moment it works like this: At first you click the login-button, this works perfectly fine. Ajax is doing his job. Then you click on the Logout-button, the first time you click on it you get a GET-method like action (which isn't supposed to happen). Then i tried clicking again on it and it logs me out perfectly. And when i try to login again it does the same as the logout button. First time doesn't work, second time it does.

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';
$nowDate = date('d-m-Y h:i:s');
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Local scripts <3 -->
    <script src="code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox">
        <div class="errorbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Oh oh!</strong> <span id="errorMessage"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="successbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="success" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Yay!</strong> <span id="successMessage"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
          ?>
        <div class="loginbox">
          <form class="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="un">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="un" id="un">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pw"><span class="important">*</span> Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pw" id="pw">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default login-button" name="login" value="Log in">Log in</button>
            <h6><span class="important">*</span> - Only needed when you have a reserved username!</h6>
          </form>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="logout">
          <form class="post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default logout-button" name="logout" value="Log out">Log out</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="choosebox">
            <?php
            $statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT id,chat_name,max_users,admin_only,online_users FROM chats');
            $statement->bind_result($id, $chat_name, $max_users, $admin_only, $online_users);
            $statement->execute();
            //if ($statement->fetch()) {
            echo '<table class="table">';
            echo '<tr><th>Chat name</th><th>Users</th><th></th></tr>';
            while ($statement->fetch()) {
              echo '<tr>';
              if ($admin_only === 1) {
                if (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] === 1) {
                  echo '<td>' . $chat_name . ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>';
                } else {
                  echo '<td>' . $chat_name . ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>';
                }
              } else {
                echo '<td>' . $chat_name . '</span></td>';
              }
              if ($max_users === 0) {
                $maxus = '&#8734;';
              } else {
                $maxus = $max_users;
              }
              echo '<td>' . $online_users . '/' . $maxus . '</td>';
              echo '<td>'
              . '<form class="post">'
              . '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="joim" value="Join">Try to join</button>'
              . '</form>'
              . '</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="chat">        
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

code.js:

```
/* Piece that acts weird */
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".post").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
  });
  $(".post").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(".post").bind('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
  });
  $(".logout-button").click(function (e) {
    $.post("logout.php", {logout: 'Log out'}, function (data, status) {
      if (status === 'success') {
        $("#chatbox").load(location.href + " #chatbox");
        $("#chatbox").load(location.href + " #chatbox");
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
  $(".login-button").click(function (e) {
    console.log('login');
    $.post("login.php", {login: 'Log in', pw: $("#pw").val(), un: $("#un").val()}, function (data, status) {
      if (status === 'success') {
        if (data !== '') {
          $(".errorbox").fadeOut();
          $("#errorMessage").html(data);
          $(".errorbox").fadeIn();
        } else {
          $("#chatbox").load(location.href + " #chatbox");
        }
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

If you want to know anything else you can ask for it.

EDIT:
If you want to test it (Just ignore the password field): [ianketje.com/chat](http://ianketje.com/chat)

EDIT 2:
I found the bug, it appears to be that my script gets ignored once i resetted the "chatbox" div. Any answers for this would be helpfull <3

Comment: Why do you need two .post submit events?

Comment: @LarryLane I was just testing with it, i tried all of those seperate and together. Normally i only have 1.

Comment: Even though I have not tested your code, but i think you need to tell the form in your code that you have to use post method, it get is the default.

add method = "post" to your form element

Comment: @KKarayat If i do that it indeed does the POST method, but i don' t want it to do the post method, i want it to do the Jquery function i created for it.

Comment: What Jquery function are you using?

Comment: @LarryLane For disabling the form action:
`$(".post").submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  });`

Comment: Can you provide the code to the login.php file or at least a watered down version that returns the data so I can help you troubleshoot it further?

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code a bit. I removed the extra submit button because you were already executing code when the user clicks on the submit button.  I removed all of the return false statements and moved the e.preventDefault() function calls to the top of the event.  That way they will prevent the default navigation. I place the following html in a login.php file for testing on my server.

login.php:

```
    <div class="logout">
          <form class="post" method="post">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default logout-button" name="logout" value="Log out">Log out</button>
          </form>
        </div>   

<div class="choosebox">
            <table class="table"><tbody><tr><th>Chat name</th><th>Users</th><th></th></tr><tr><td>The admin hole <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></td><td>0/∞</td><td><form class="post"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="joim" value="Join">Try to join</button></form></td></tr><tr><td>The non-admin hole</td><td>0/50</td><td><form class="post"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="joim" value="Join">Try to join</button></form></td></tr></tbody></table>          </div>
```

Modified JavaScript for code.js:

```
//Changed the beginning of this function call to prevent conflicts
//with any other javascript libraries loaded.
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {



    $(".logout-button").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("logging out");

      $.post("logout.php", { logout: 'Log out' }, function (data, status) {



      if (status === 'success') {

          $("#chatbox").load(location.href + " #chatbox");

      }

    });





    });

  $(".login-button").click(function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      console.log("login");

    $.post("http://localhost/login.php", {login: 'Log in', pw: $("#pw").val(), un: $("#un").val()}, function (data, status) {
      if (status === 'success') {
        if (data !== '') {
          $(".errorbox").fadeOut();
          $("#errorMessage").html(data);
          $(".errorbox").fadeIn();
        } else {
          $("#chatbox").load(location.href + " #chatbox");
        }
      }
    });


  });
});
```

Comment: I dived a little deeper into your live website and did some testing. Please check out my edited answer.

Comment: This also doesn't work. I'm getting kinda ignored, i'm gonna do some testing on other browser if that doesn't work, i'm gonna recode it, But thanks alot for your help <3 if i solve it i'll answer it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('body').on('submit' , '.post' , funtion(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    # the rest
})
```